# Powershell Export-Csv issue

Tags: powershell

I try to export a file in csv format from an `psobject`.
Within of my `psoobject` I have a custom properties from multiples variables:

```
$1 = 8
$2 = 8
$props = @{

    'test' = "$1/$2"
}

$csv = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props

$csv | select * | Export-Csv  C:\Users\adm-tc5190\Desktop\report\v2\test.csv
```

As you can see my 'test' properties is an object from 2 variables $1 and $2.
But when I export-csv in my file I get an incorrect output from my 'test' properties.

Here is the output that I get in csv file:

8-Aug but must be 8/8

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: are you using Excel or similar program to open test.csv? Try to open it with notepad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in the csv file *is* the string `"8/8"` - it's Excel that assumes that string to be a partial date, and formats it that way.

You can verify by looking at the actual contents of the file:

```
PS C:\> Get-Content "C:\Users\adm-tc5190\Desktop\report\v2\test.csv"
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"test"
"8/8"
```

Instead of opening the csv file with Excel directly, you can import the data with the "Text Import Wizard" (**Data** tab -> Get External Data -> **From Text**), and specify "Text" as the data type in the last step

Comment: Hi Mathias, yes you are right there is a problem with my csv file and not with my PS script. Do you know if there are any way to save my csv file directly in text format with my PS script?

Answer (score 0):

If you can explain what your trying to accomplish perhaps we can provide a better way?  The default behavior of Excel is to try to determine data type and 8/8 will be "translated" to a date format, this is an excel behavior and has nothing to do with Powershell or how it's treating the data.

I was successful in recreating the issue by double clicking on the csv file and opening directly in Excel. If you open a blank excel file and import, as Mathias R. Jessen mentioned below, specifying in step 3 of the text import wizard "Column data format" = text, I believe you will get the behavior you expect.  It's probably more work than you want but that is how you get the result you are looking for.